# How do I create a distribution group that is dynamic

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, distribution-lists

I know that title may sound pretty dumb but I'm not looking for "create a dynamic distribution group!" as an answer.  Let me explain.

A question I posted a little bit ago confirmed that you cannot expand a dynamic distribution group.  Because I have a boss that seeks impossible things to ask for, he wants to be able to see the people in the distribution groups.

I want the low maintenance of a dynamic distribution group, but I also want to satisfy my boss' [insert harsh word here] request.

I was thinking maybe a PowerShell script that deletes the distribution group and then recreates it based on who's in an OU.  I run it every time we hire/fire someone?

Or is there a way that I can keep the dynamic distribution group and then create a standard distribution group from that every time someone gets hired/fired?

Someone has to have had this [insert harsh word here] request before, can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a identity management solution for this. Then you can create workflows who enters or leaves the company whom wil be added/removed to the defined groups. Have you taken a look what [Forefront Identity Manager 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621258%28WS.10%29.aspx) can you do for you? And specific to you question: [Introduction to Distribution Group Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534915%28WS.10%29.aspx)